# How do you disable SSL certificate validation when spooling emails with swiftMailer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, php-5.6, symfony-2.7

this is a follow up question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454920/swiftmailer-php-how-to-disable-ssl-certificate-validation)

In PHP 5.6, *'verify_peer'* and *'verify_peer_name'* by default are set to [true](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544#issuecomment-61481589) and this is causing connectivity issues with gmail for me.

A fix was implemented [here](https://github.com/Amunak/swiftmailer/commit/89f666ae9becab7e3cf3d529ebc7ee708367240b) which lets you *setStreamOptions* of an *EsmtpTransport* allowing you to disable these checks. This is fine, however I am spooling emails on symfony and the transporter used when spooling is *SpoolTransport* which does not allow you to *setStreamOptions*.

> I could could disable the SSL check by modifying the function
>   "_establishSocketConnection" in StreamBuffer.php and adding these
>   lines before stream_socket_client command:
>
> ```
> $options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
> $options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
> ```

However that is a dirty fix and involves changing vendor code.

Is there any other option to disable these checks when spooling? My swifmailer config is below for reference

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport:  smtp
    host:       smtp.gmail.com
    username:   XXX
    password:   XXX
    port:       465
    encryption: ssl
    spool:
        type: file
        path: '%kernel.root_dir%/spool'
```

Comment: where are you doing the spooling? isn't on the same machine?

Comment: It is on the same machine @Edwin

Answer (score 2):

Get the transport object and call this:

`$transport->setStreamOptions(array('ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false)));`

In Symfony, probably something like this:
`$transport = $this->get("swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport");`

Comment: The transporter object when spooling is Swift_Transport_SpoolTransport and that does not have a setStreamOptions method :(

Comment: ah, the actual class i meant was Swift_SmtpTransport

Comment: Yup, but I cannot spool with that transporter unfortunately